# WCF Service Self Hosting Trouble

Tags: .net, windows-services, wcf, self-hosting

I'm trying to host a WCF Service inside a Windows Service which I am starting through a console app.  Each service is its own project as is the console app.  I've copied the app.config from the WCF Service library into the app.config of the console app, but I keep getting "Service has zero application endpoints...".  I've read in a few places that the error means my type references are not fully qualified, but I've double (triple, quadruple...) checked that.  And I'm pretty sure I have an app.config.  There are 3 exes in my debug directory: Console App, Console App vshost, Win Service.  The Win Service didn't have an app.config, so I tried copying its app.config in case it was looking for it, but no luck.  I also checked to make sure the configs were named correctly (<program>.exe.config).

Here's what I'm using.  My console app creates an instance of `JobSchdeuler` and calls `JobSchedulerConsoleStart`.

Host Code:

```
public partial class JobScheduler : ServiceBase
{
    ServiceHost jobServiceHost = null;

    public JobScheduler()
    {
        ServiceName = "JobSchedulerService";
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region Service Init/Uninit

    /// <summary>
    /// OnStart
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        if (jobServiceHost != null)
        {
            jobServiceHost.Close();
        }

        jobServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(JobSchedulerWCF.JobService));

        jobServiceHost.Open();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnStop
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        if (jobServiceHost != null)
        {
            jobServiceHost.Close();
            jobServiceHost = null;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Debugging

    public void JobSchedulerConsoleStart()
    {
        this.OnStart(null);
        Console.WriteLine("Service Started.");

        ProcessInput();

        Console.WriteLine("Service Stopped.");
        this.OnStop();
    }

    private void ProcessInput()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="JobSchedulerWCF.Service1Behavior" name="JobSchedulerWCF.JobService, JobSchedulerWCF">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="JobSchedulerWCF.IJobServiceController, JobSchedulerWCF">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:12345/jobService"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="JobSchedulerWCF.Service1Behavior">
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
                        set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
                      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
                      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>          
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you also provide us with the host code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to the bottom of this.  There was something slightly off in the config/project.  I rebuilt the solution and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Do your configuration files are named

- Console.App.exe.config
- Win.Service.exe.config

?

EDIT: If I remember correctly there was an issue with the Beta version of WCF and Service names.

Try to change

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="JobSchedulerWCF.Service1Behavior" name="JobSchedulerWCF.JobService, JobSchedulerWCF">
```

to

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="JobSchedulerWCF.Service1Behavior" name="JobSchedulerWCF.JobService">
```

Remove the assembly name in your config files.

Please let me know if that solves the problem. I didn't tied it.